# Under what conditions does the variance-to-mean-ratio decrease when a random variable is multiplied by another?

Tags: variance, expected-value

Let $A$ and $B$ be two independent random variables.

Variance to mean ratio is defined as $D=\frac{\sigma^2}{\mu}$. Are there any conditions under which the VMR of $AB$ is less than the VMR of $A$?

Comment: Since this ratio is not unitless, it will decrease (in absolute value) merely by scaling $A.$

Comment: @whuber Okay. I guess my question is, is there any way to show that $AB$ is 'more noisy' than $A$? You have two (independent) sources of stochasticity after all.

Comment: But what do you mean by "more noisy"?  Are you concerned about a particular application or problem where "noisiness" has a meaning you can quantify or articulate?

Comment: @whuber Consider the case where we have some probability distribution $A\sim \rho(\theta)$ which we can control the parameter of and e.g. $B\sim \mathcal{N}$. The problem of maximizing the expectation of $A$ with respect to $\theta$, using for example stochastic gradient descent is going to be a lot easier than maximizing $AB$ assuming $B$ does not depend on $\theta$.

Comment: @whuber Perhaps my problem can be stated as such: How to prove that $A$ is a better/worse estimator of $\mathbb{E}[F]$ than $AB$, when we don't know if $F=F(A,B)$ or $F=F(A)$?

Comment: That's a puzzling statement, because distributions ($F$) are not functions of estimators (which themselves are functions of random variables).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mean and variance of the product of two independent random variables with first two moments $\mu_A, \mu_B, \sigma^2_a, \sigma^2_B$ are:

$$\begin{align}
\mu_{AB} &= \mu_A \mu_B \\ 
\sigma^2_{AB} &= \mu^2_A\sigma^2_B + \mu^2_B\sigma^2_A + \sigma^2_A\sigma^2_B
\end{align}$$

If we take the ratio of the two ratios $D_{AB} = \sigma^2_{AB}/\mu_{AB}$ and $D_A = \sigma^2_A/\mu_A$ we get:

$${D_{AB} \over D_A} = {\sigma^2_{AB} \over \sigma^2_A}{\mu_{A} \over \mu_{AB}}$$

which expands to:

$${D_{AB} \over D_A} = {\mu^2_A\sigma^2_B \over\mu_B\sigma^2_A} + \mu_B +{\sigma^2_B \over \mu_B}$$

which, obviously, can be rearranged some, but not in any particularly useful way.  You can compare this ratio to $1$ to see whether the VMR of $AB$ is less than or equal to the VMR of $A$; obviously sometimes it will be and sometimes it won't.

Similarly, subtracting $D_A$ from $D_{AB}$ results in:

$$D_{AB}-D_A = \sigma^2_{AB} = {\mu_A \over \mu_B\sigma^2_B} + {\mu_B \over \mu_A\sigma^2_A} + {\sigma^2_A\sigma^2_B \over \mu_A\mu_B} - {\sigma^2_A \over \mu_A}$$

which is not especially helpful either; nonetheless, you can compare the difference to $0$  to see whether the VMR of $AB$ is less than or equal to the VMR of $A$; again, sometimes it will be and sometimes it won't.

Comment: You could write $D_{AB}/D_A =D_B [1+ \mu_A/D_A] + \mu_B =D_B [1+ \mu_A/D_A + \mu_B/D_B]$ which might be easier to deal with. We could also try writing $\mu_X/D_X = 1/C_X^2$ where $C$ is the coefficient of variation, so $D_{AB}/D_A =D_B [1+ \mu_A/D_A + \mu_B/D_B] = D_B[1+1/C_A^2+1/C_B^2]$. If the coefficient of variation of $A$ is very large, this is approximately
$D_B[1+1/C_B^2] = D_B + \mu_B$, so (assuming no errors there), at least when $C_A$ is large relative to $D_B$, we might pursue making both $\mu_B$ and $D_B$  small simultaneously (i.e. $\mu_B<<1$ and $\sigma^2_B<<\mu_B$)..

Comment: That wandered about too much but it still helps us to see the territory; from there it's relatively straightforward to use your derivation of the ratio to identify suitable possibilities. e.g. consider a case where: $C_A=\sigma^2_A/\mu_A^2=2$, 
with $\mu_B=.4$ and
$\sigma^2_B=.1$ so
$D_B = .25$,  $C^2_B = .1/.16$.

Then it looks like (again assuming I didn't make an error somewhere) $D_{AB}/D_A = 0.25\cdot[1+1/2+0.16/0.1]<1$, as needed.

Comment: @Glen_b - I did think of simplifying as in your very first suggestion above, but it seemed to me that no matter what you do, you wind up starting with the two means and two variances.  Maybe I'm being too reductionist, though, and stating the conditions in terms of $D$ or $C$ as you suggest makes it easier to understand the various relationships.

Comment: I'm not sure the extent to which any of it helps anyone beyond what you did, but once I had that we need to try to make $\mu_B$ and $D_B$ small simultaneously, it made it easier for me to come up with an example, so it helped me understand it a little better at least. But once there, I can pretty much see that from what you have anyway.